# Прописная-строчная: "свет луны" и "влияние Москвы"

Tags: прописная-строчная

Меня тут убедили, что в примере: "свет луны", Луна пишется с маленькой буквы. Но тогда в примере: " На форуме влияние Москвы сдерживало союзников", "Москва" надо писать с маленькой буквы? Здесь же подразумевалось не населенный пункт, а политики с армией.

Answer (score 7):

Свет луны - это свет диска, луна - не имя собственное, не планета, а Москва - имя собственное, речь именно о городе, но в переносном смысле.Да, здесь не населённый пункт имеется в виду, а те, кто живёт в Москве, вернее, её верхушка, т.е. это приём метонимии  - перенос смысла по смежности имён. Поэтому пишется с прописной буквы.

Answer (score 3):

Москва - с заглавной, это имя собственное, в каком бы значении ни использовалось, оно нарицательным не стало. То, что под ним в определенных контекстах понимаются властные структуры государства, столицей которого является Москва, ничего не меняет, все равно имя собственное, да и значение тут переносное. С Луной/луной вообще аналогии никакой не вижу.

Да и с самой Луной/луной сложнее. Можно и "свет Луны", если имеется в виду не нарицательное значение небесного месяца, а именно астрономическое тело. Аналогично и с Солнцем. В обоих случаях "земное" значение стало нарицательным.

Comment: "Свет Луны" с точки зрения астрономии какое-то бессмысленное сочетание, так как спутник Земли не испускает света, а лишь отражает его. Мы же не говорим *свет ботинок (шкафа и пр.)*

Comment: _Марк Из: Мы же не говорим свет ботинок (шкафа и пр.)_ === Но  "свет Луны" всё же говорим.  См.: _"Свет Луны в той или иной мере поляризован…"_ https://books.google.ru/books?id=LFD-AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&dq=%22%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8B%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU_urtzs7KAhVH8XIKHTlKATM4FBDoAQhDMAY#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8B%22&f=false

Comment: *Свет Луны" с точки зрения астрономии какое-то бессмысленное сочетание,* - отчасти согласен, но это не вопрос орфографии. У меня-то этот свет проявлялся исключительно для обсуждения предлагаемой параллели с "Москвой". Ну а потом, Вы же написали, пусть и в кавычках это сочетание, значит некая потребность в самом понятии есть.